# Stack Overflow Annual User Survey 2012

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-overflow-developer-survey

This year's survey is officially open! We've added a few new questions based on your feedback from last year and we are really looking forward to publishing the results in January.

Once you've taken the survey, we will send you (US or Canada) a limited edition sticker as a small, yet terrific, token of our appreciation.

[To participate, click here.](https://www.surveymonkey.com/s/T59Q82L)

Comment: I want stickers in Europe too. =( (Yeah, shipping costs, I know.)

Comment: Seriously? You write jQuery but not javascript?!

Comment: I love stickers! Therefore, I have completed the survey!

Comment: I work providing web services to educational institutions.  Could you make it so we could select both?  Also, it's a startup.  The title that best describes what I do is "EVERYTHING".

Comment: "Which of the following best describes your occupation?" - So there are only web, mobile, desktop, or database developers?  Enterprise level services aren't in there?  Very lacking, but maybe because I'm not accurately represented. =)

Comment: You have offices in the UK/Europe. You should be able to organise a bulk delivery to there and then post the stickers locally.

Comment: "Including yourself, how many developers / peers are employed at your company?"  Which one do you want?  Developers or peers?  There's a distinction between the two, unless you and both, in which case you should use **and**, not a "/".

Comment: Why can "Which of the following languages or technologies have you used significantly in the past year?" be answered with "jQuery", but not "JavaScript"?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've incorporated it into the survey!

Comment: The section asking about Careers 2.0 should have had an option "I got my current job via Careers 2.0"

Comment: Is there a difference between `jQuery` and `JQuery`?

Comment: Perhaps its obvious, but what is the privacy policy for this survey?

Comment: Sticker?  No T-Shirt/hoodie?  :(

Comment: @casperOne my interpretation: not everyone Is a developer. If you are, how many developers. If not, how many others that do similar work to you.

Comment: When can we expect something in Asia? :)

Comment: I'd also like to know the difference between `jQuery` and `JQuery`... a tech person must not have written the survey :p

Comment: @Austin it's a trap, if you select JQuery you don't know what are you talking about... it is jQuery, of course. :)

Comment: Too bad the survey is completely biased against academia.

Comment: I found the list of 'industries' pretty lacking.  What's the right category for 'consumer electronics'?

Comment: I want stickers in India too...

Comment: A quick note. I use an ad blocker, but not all the time. I have adblock disabled on stackoverflow(on my work computer anyway) because as a 10K+ user, I really barely even see ads as it is and there are some genuinely good ads. Just thought I'd throw in my 2 cents because stackoverflow has always had the best ads in the business I think :)

Comment: can't select answers in Chrome on ipad (safari works)

Comment: Why only US/Canada?? Stackoverflow is also **highly used by Indian** users.

Comment: Why is Alison holding one of Anna Lear's cats! :)

Comment: Please make those to India too :)

Comment: Users from india also love SO as much as US/Canada users... so  plzz include india also.......

Comment: The "Occupation" categories were so weird I ended up selecting "Other".

Comment: StackExchange should have had the foresight to first ask SO/UX users how to design the perfect survey.

Comment: No love here Philippines and Singapore? Really hope we can get the stickers even if its on much later time. we can wait, hope SO love us back :)

Comment: Submitted my answer to survey still anyway, enjoyed answering them too

Comment: Not sticker for Malaysian?

Comment: no stickers, no data - sorry ;)

Comment: Such a short collection of countries, why not use the full list? It's a bit of downer for me in Israel.

Comment: I'm in the UK. I don't mind going to your London office to get the stickers, but... I want my sticker!

Comment: Oh come on.. We dutchies founded the united states and we don't get stickers? I DEMAND YOU RETURN NEW AMSTERDAM (New York) TO US!

Comment: So much fuss over _stickers_?! O_o  Very tempted to offer a custom sticker service - for just £100 I'll send TEN stickers, each with a hand-drawn logo of your choice; free delivery to UK mainland. Who's interested? :P

Comment: @PeterBoughton I'll have a 100 stickers. The logo should be a street map to your house, or wherever you are going to store the £1000 I pay for them. What kind of a discount will you do me if I order 1000?

Comment: :D I guess that would be a map to wherever my bank stores their servers... if you've got a plan for getting into those, I don't think you'd need a discount. :P

Comment: Hmm no love for Windows Phone developers?

Comment: At the risk of sounding stupid, and as someone who hasn't done this before, why would I want to fill this survey in? Is it just a basic census of SO users? Is it used internally as marketing or advertisement material?

Comment: *"we will send you (US or Canada)"*  I'd have done the survey for no offers of incentives, but that irritates me so much that you can ask someone else.  :-/  (It seems the survey might be 'ever so slightly' biased towards the opinions of them from the north Americas.)

Comment: If you don't send stickers everybody, please post those images here. So we will manage to make stickers ourselves.

Comment: Why not just suck it up and send people who vote stickers regardless of country.. There really are more countries in the world than US/Canada.

Comment: Australia needs stickers, *neeeds*

Comment: I am living on the Moon, send stickers for me too!

Comment: Why not this post as community wiki?

Comment: I want StackOverFlow stickers too ,even if its a .jpg ,I'm from Pakistan :)

Comment: I want a pony..

Comment: Stickers for India!!

Comment: How about Stickers to `North African` Users :(

Comment: How about automation engineers? What categories do they fall in ?

Comment: I didn't continue the survey because **How old are you?** is a required question.

Comment: Is it possible to see last year's survey?

Comment: @Louis The results are linked to from [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/hey-there-stranger/?cb=1) and you seemingly can contact SE for the data.

Comment: I want a unicorn!!

Comment: How to "unsubmit" the survey? In the 21st century, if you insist on living in stone age (stickers only in US and Canada!?), I want my responses back.

Comment: **WOW** All you need to do is mention `stickers`?

Comment: Overall Alexa rank of Stackoverflow is 81, In United States 150, In Canada 70, In United Kingdom 67 but in India it is 25. Still No stickers for India. Are you kidding ?

Comment: People: the reason that only the US and Canada are getting stickers is because it gets really expensive to mail things overseas. The SE team still loves you nonetheless.

Comment: Why can't we have email stickers ?! :(

Comment: I think the European members deserve a medal if we can't have a sticker...

Comment: Why not stickers to europe? An enveloppe like the others, 2 stickers and there we go. Yeah of course a couple of stamps

Comment: -1 because no stickers to India. Send me a sticker, and I will remove the downvote. ;)

Comment: We need Stickers in India too.

Comment: this will help IT people of Pakistan too if Stickers are available here.

Comment: Who'd have thought stickers would be such a sticking point? They should mention the sticker delivery issues up front, as I'm not sure I would have divulged my precious personal information if I had known I wasn't going to get stickers.

Comment: @AlisonS [here is the full list of countries](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/country_names_and_code_elements) Just in case you don't know how to provide it in the first question...

Comment: if these stickers are so popular why not sell them :)

Comment: we need merchandise!

Comment: No stickers for Heather :'(

Comment: @DamienOvereem not true the wikings did (Leif the merry to be exact) but you can have some stickers as long as they get to Denmark as well :)

Comment: We eager to have sticker in India..

Comment: @Runefs I can live with that :) Besides. I have friends in Denmark, so all is well :)

Comment: Send some to INDIA too :)

Comment: This assumes I'm working at a company... What if I'm a student yet?

Comment: Survey was not open for 'moonlighters' -- people such as myself that do other IT during the daytime, and hack code (while reading SO) at night.  Were the survey Q directed at day job company, or other?

Comment: No stickers for Europe? I guess Uruguay is out of the question :(

Comment: Thats too bad. And a very undemoctratic way of showing bias. For users outside US/Can, why not charge a shipping cost.

Comment: Why not put all the countries in the combobox? Seems weird that countries like Japan, China or Korea are all "Other Asia".

Comment: It was extremely disappointing to know you won't be shipping stickers to other parts of the world!

Comment: Exciting technologies is pretty poor, and have no free text field. What about Scala, Go, GWT, etc.?

Comment: I was hoping for a survey about Stack Overflow (like, what we think needs improvement). Instead I got a survey about *me*. That's silly. I already *know* about me.

Comment: I want sticker in Hong Kong, too.

Comment: No Gangnam Style T-Shirt? Come on

Comment: We need selection for Japan, and want to have stickers!

Comment: So when do these stickers get sent out? I completed the survey about 10 days ago and no sticker yet.

Comment: I think there are too few european countries to choose from :-(

Comment: Some questions are really lacking options. Is there nobody anybody anymore that develop non-web server applications?

Comment: Consider india too...

Comment: @Once you've taken the survey, we will send you (US or Canada) a limited edition sticker as a small, yet terrific, token of our appreciation. *THUMBS DOWN*

Comment: Where's my MUSTANG GT 5SPD?

Comment: Stickers for India too...!!!

Comment: hmm, "Just me!" or 1-3?

Comment: oh ho, a trick question.  had to log in to careers 2.0 to see if I had a profile...

Comment: SO stickers for the win, too bad only US and Canada

Comment: ok..if no stickers, then give me a gold badge for wasting my 10 minutes on survey!

Comment: Why not India :) but will do the survey. <3 the site

Comment: glad to be from Canada :)

Comment: I'll pay for you to ship me one of those to Brazil!

Comment: Stickers in Europe indeed!! :D

Comment: FYI the survey is now closed! Stay tuned for the results!

Comment: @AlisonS When do the stickers ship?

Comment: @AustinHenley Stickers will be mailed out this week via First Class Mail. So you should have them next week. Please let me know when you get them!

Comment: @AlisonS I just got my sticker!! :D

Comment: I just got my sticker too! <3 Stackoverflow!

Comment: Hey!  My sticker came in the mail yesterday (Kansas City - USA)!  I can't believe it!  Thanks!

Comment: @AlisonS Stickers arrived yesterday. Thanks! I am going to frame this envelope...

Comment: "This survey is currently closed and results are being tabulated" :-(

Comment: **I want STICKERS**. I'm from ***INDIA***. *Should I shift to US or canada to get one.*:p

Comment: @AlisonS How about Australia and APAC? :D How can I participate in the Survery if you only want users from US/Canada :P

Comment: 2013 edition: *[Stack Overflow Annual User Survey 2013 Edition](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211850)*

Answer (score 115):

The last page with questions about advertisements.. option "I use adblocker" should make the rest of the questions in this block non-mandatory. I can't say anything about the adverts if I never seen them.

Comment: I don't block them, but I also have no opinion because I don't look over there at them. I marked the questions "Neutral"

Comment: Neutral/Agree/Disagree doesn't even make sense with all questions, even if you fill don't use adblocker.  "I have purchased a product from the ads". That's a yes/no questions. Not Agree/Disagree

Comment: Blocking ads is like theft of services.  Thanks for making it harder for Stack Overflow to keep running!

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: I assume that is a joke, right? Otherwise the blind and visually impaired are outright crooks by your standards.

Comment: @sixlettervariables That's kind of an absurd comparison, isn't it?  Intentionally blocking something vs being physiologically unable to see something are two very different things.  And I'm sure the ads can be processed by screen readers just like everything else (via alt-text and whatnot). (Not that I necessarily agree that blocking ads is theft)

Comment: @sixlettervariables ok, so how do you pay for your consumption of the resources that SO requires for operation?  Presumably you understand that it requires money to operate and provide the site?  Where does that money come from?

Comment: @dash-tom-bang If someone is going to block ads, they certainly weren't going to click on them (which I imagine is how value / cost of ads is determined - number of clicks / purchases).

Comment: @jadarnel27 Sure, if you're not going to buy that software/book/CD anyway you may as well steal it right off the store shelf.

Comment: You're contributing whenever you use a site because you raise its all-important click/page view count, which allows them to get more money from advertisers.

Comment: @Lance, but you don't get impressions recorded (since the images don't download) which is also an important metric.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: unless I retransmit an ad-free version of SE, I'm not stealing anything. Besides, I use the network to generate content *for* the network.

Comment: @jadarnel27: not really. If you can't physically see an ad that somebody paid to put in front of you, how is that different than not seeing it because you block it? Money was spent on a wasted impression. I'd imagine the blind would be even more prone to ad blocking to remove extraneous text from their browser! Buncha felons if you ask me.

Comment: _"unless I retransmit an ad-free version of SE, I'm not stealing anything"_ - even if you did that, you wouldn't be stealing anything; the content is specifically licensed to allow sharing (with [fair attribution](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)).

Comment: @sixlettervariables It's about intent, silly.

Comment: @PeterBoughton: I meant literal retransmission, a la *proxy* simply sans ads.

Comment: @jadarnel27: I'm not sure intent matters as motive is not required to commit a crime. Besides, the T&S state that we're responsible for our own hardware and software to browse the site and make no reference to what they are required to do. SE entered into the agreement with ad companies, not their users.

Comment: Where is the survey?

Comment: What's wrong with blocking ads if you stay outside US and Canada?

Comment: I use an ad blocker, but have now turned it off for this site. We'll see how it goes. If they get too annoying, I'll turn it back on.

Comment: Doesn't this question also refer to the sponsered stories/ads at the top of search results? Are these also blocked with an adblocker?

Comment: Well said @sixlettervariables, I WANT MY SHARE!

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: There are many more ways to contribute to the site than by seeing ads.  Helping to make the site valuable draws users, some of whom, one might presume, do see the ads.

Comment: Dont use an ad blocker!  I guess they will need some other revenue, like donations, maybe a donate if you block the ads button.

Comment: @jadarnel27 alert: huge division by zero error possibility

Comment: @DaEsel I like your user name.

Comment: It really turns me off when stackoverflow closes perfectly good questions.

Answer (score 72):

First, a bug report. The "Which of the following languages or technologies have you used significantly in the past year?" question lists both jQuery and jQuery. I suspect that's an oversight and only jQuery should remain.

Second, I don't understand how you define "company" for very large organizations that are broken down. For someone like me, there's a massive conglomerate on top with different businesses inside of it, which are often broken down into [SBUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_business_unit) and then sites. The number grows from 500 to a site to 10k for the business. More clarity should be provided.

Comment: -1 you can never have enough jQuery.

Comment: @Yannis But you can have too much JQuery. jQuery > JQuery and I don't even do this new fangled web stuff.

Comment: I made sure to enter jQuery under "Other" along with these to make sure it gets noted.

Comment: +1 jQuery vs JQuery. Get it right its `jayQuery`, imagine if that was a control question! jay is John Resig's pet hamster.

Answer (score 65):

I notice one of the questions asks "If you make a software product, how does your company make money?". There's no answer provided to that for "it doesn't".

This also implies that my making a software product has some direct connection to my company making money (once again assuming that the company does, in fact, make money).

Comment: Yep. Also, how much money does the University that I work for make? Is it really relevant...

Comment: After this question I exited survey got me paranoid, didn't want to go against my company policy by mistake.

Comment: And what about internal software that doesn't make money but helps other software make money...?

Comment: Yea, lots of folks make sofware that the company uses, to make money, not to sell.

Answer (score 54):

The survey is pretty much geared towards those who have a job in IT. Quite a few of us code for fun and/or are students. Most of the questions make no sense from these perspectives. Maybe a few more options could be added to certain questions so that it makes sense for these two groups to answer them?

Comment: They don't *want* to know about you, because you make the statistics worse for advertisers :)

Comment: Yeah, this was my objection as well.  I figured they probably don't care too much about getting responses from outside the tech industry, since SO is after all a tech-oriented site. (also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158497 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158523 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158668)

Comment: It sounded to me like the survey was to improve Careers 2.0, which to me seems perfectly suited to students, especially the ones that want to get jobs someday.

Comment: @asmeurer: The questions _still_ aren't tailopred towards students, most ask for stuff that only makes sense if you have a job. (no. of coworkers, salary, etc)

Comment: Yea, maybe they need a branch, that would improve the data a bunch.

Comment: I gave up on the survey because of the same problem as students from the opposite point of view. I'm retired.

Answer (score 50):

What are the privacy considerations of this? If one wants the swag, one has to link one's name, salary with an address. Is that being sold?

Did I miss a privacy blurb stating SO will not sell your information related to this questionaire?

Comment: Not enough people asking this.  For a sticker, nah not worth it.  Give me the image online and I will print out the sticker

Comment: I asked that in a comment soon after the post came out, I still haven't seen anything about it...

Comment: @Jack Found your comment and upvoted it.

Comment: How is this so far down! Upvote.

Comment: I'm kind of concerned no SO employee or mod has addressed this...

Answer (score 45):

I completed the survey and just want to add two things about the last part. In Canada we don't have:

- A state
- A zipcode

The equivalent would be:

- Province
- Postal Code

To some of you this may seem irrelevant, but too many sites forget about this detail and most of the time formats do not match. (Zip Format: xxxxx / PostalCode: format xxx - xxx).

Comment: If there was a site where I would expect these things to be (for once) handled correctly, this would be the one.  Maybe *this* is why you can't ship stickers to Europe?

Comment: ...Or maybe it's because the format is handled by SurveyMonkey, and not Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JezenThomas you're right. Just felt like pointing it out though

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk I made this edit, thanks!

Comment: @AlisonS No problem. Will I still get my sticker if I entered my infos as Zip and State? :P

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Absolutely!

Comment: Canada? It exists? I thought that was just an urban legend.  :-D

Comment: @TomCollins Yeah we just got electricity a few weeks ago.

Comment: try living outside northern america and it's even worse

Comment: @Runefs I guess so ! The only thing is it was clearly stated U.S and Canada so I was wondering why one of the two wasn't listed

Comment: I love those forms that, even though they *do* seem to recognize German postal differences, still require a "State/Province" field.  There are "States" (called Länder), but they don't feature in the postal address *at all*.
But that's just a personal off-topic rant/peeve :D

Answer (score 39):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Thank you! You love Kiwis after all :)
Here're the current options for keepsake (note "Australasia")
[image]

---

I got stuck on the first question.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Asian_countries_by_GDP
https://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/asia.htm

No "New Zealand" to be seen.  Australia is both a country and continent, but New Zealand is not part of it.

I guess you didn't want responses from New Zealand then?

Comment: There's also "Australasia" (now) which I suppose includes NZ.

Comment: What option is present there now? I've already completed survey so I don't know

Comment: @Andrey - You can remove cookies.. *shhh*

Comment: Where's Oceania? Not all islands belong to Australasia. [Here's proper divisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Regions_of_the_world).

Comment: Maybe there should be just "OTHER"?

Comment: And what about the Caribbean?

Answer (score 37):

It appears you have completely omitted anything related to the world of academia. "Education" does not work because I am a researcher, not an instructor.

And all the questions about your company don't fit well for asking about a university/department. How should I know how much my "company" makes? The department gets funding from many people/organizations and professors have their own funding on top of that.

Answer (score 27):

I would think that a large percentage of users on SO as well as on a lot of SE sites are students. SO, how are you expecting this group of users to fill the survey? In its current form, it's rather obviously not considering students to be a major part of the site.

Comment: This reply is similar to http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158502/169101

Comment: @RobW Nothing wrong in making ourselves be heard as this is a discussion ..

Comment: No problem. Since this is meta, I upvoted both answers :p

Answer (score 23):

This survey is for employed people only?

[image]
(click on image to zoom)

I don't work in ANY industry – I am a student.

Comment: I recall that at another question, you were able to answer that you're a student.

Comment: Yeah but why radio button when they can put checkbox ? In this way, user1774214 could check 0 checkbox and then, later, precise he is student !

Comment: Unemployed people are not interesting, as they have no money and can't be sold to business customers.

Answer (score 21):

Under "What other departments / roles do you interact with regularly?" it would be best to include:

- Engineers / Technologists (e.g. mechanical, electrical, or nuclear)
- Research Staff

...as I have nothing to call the engineering folks.

Comment: I think engineer is too broad term. Maybe, developer or programmer would be better

Comment: @AndreyBotalov I don't think the mechanical and electrical engineers I work with would like to be called "developer" or "programmer"...

Comment: Yet I think job title should be another as developers are also called engineers. Developers were the first I thought about when I saw "engineer"

Comment: I don't recall art or other content creation being available as an option either, for that matter.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: I think they lumped them in with "Design".

Comment: was interested in what you did for work and judging by your profile your a champion!

Comment: In my organization, the engineering folks are typically called "developers" ^_^

Comment: @sixlettervariables - ah, perhaps.  In my industry that is a distinct job from design, and our use of the terms "design" and "designer" imply something completely different from what most of the industry means.  We hire people who actually (physically) paint and sculpt to build our UIs.

Answer (score 20):

"Tester/QA Engineer" isn't available as a choice in the occupation selector. It should be available. I think the number of SO users with such a job is large enough to be taken into account.

Similarly, the option "Developers" is absent in "What other departments/roles do you interact with regularly?"

Answer (score 19):

Why don't you simply list all countries of the world in the "Country or Region" selection box? Your choices are almost random it seems. For example in Europe you're listing Russia, France, Germany, Italy, United Kingdom and the Netherlands. Ok, you got the first 5 countries by population, but the Netherlands is the 10th by population, you skipped Spain, Ukraine, Poland and Romania.

Why suffer all this criticism when you could simply list *all* countries. It seems like half the "Answers" to this "Question" are related to missing or ambiguous countries or regions. Not to mention it's a "delicate" subject. I mean, I'm from Romania, why are Germans listed and not us? Sure there are many countries, but if you know they're all, you'll immediately find your country in an alphabetical listing. In my case there are only 3 countries that start with the letter "R". You'll then be able to aggregate the data as you wish: by continent, by spoken language, by average temperature in January.

Answer (score 18):

Where's the generic "Programmer" option for "Which of the following best describes your occupation?"

I basically do anything they need that's programming related, including but not limited to:

- Building/Maintaining websites and web applications
- Building/Maintaining custom desktop applications
- Building/Maintaining add-ons for existing 3rd party software
- Building/Maintaining reports
- Database administration
- IT/Tech Support

Comment: +1 Same here. I missed the generic option as well, I selected "other".

Comment: I would venture to say that most professional programmers are working on business applications.  A large percentage of them run on what they are calling "back-end" servers, and may not have anything to do with http but what the people here might call "legacy" platforms, but this is where business runs, and anyone with less than "11+" years of experience is probably a junior member of the team.

Answer (score 16):

Under "Which technology products do you own?", I believe you forgot one important one:

[image: Computer]

Comment: I think it's assumed that more 99% of SO users own it.

Comment: @AndreyBotalov I would think 99.99%

Comment: @AndreyBotalov  I think that is a rash assumption.  Times change, and if a student has access to a desktop PC at school, and owns an iPad or Android tablet, they might be tempted to try and avoid the cost of maintaining their own desktop PC.  The bottom line though is that if you don't ask, you'll never find out different..

Comment: @AndrewThompson iPad or Android tablets can be also called computers

Comment: Yeah I was a bit puzzled by this one too. I answered on the assumption that there was an implied "not counting desktop/laptop computers" qualification.

Comment: @AndreyBotalov they are both available options

Comment: Perhaps some people code directly on their Wii...

Comment: my nook runs CM10; do I check nook, android, and android tablet?  :)

Answer (score 15):

"In an average week, how do you spend your time?"

Is this just at work, or in total?  I assumed at work at first, but then saw commuting on the list.

Comment: Yeah, are we talking about the amount of internet surfing at work, or in total? Because that then brings in the "surfing while commuting" option.

Comment: Once I saw commuting I realised I could put in more that zero for the learning/study aspect... But I forgot to fix up the bit about surfing the internet.

Answer (score 14):

**Please rate the Advertising you've seen on Stack Overflow**

The way that question is presented is a bit `out-of-whack`, in my opinion.  It provides a ratings scale on a question that would be better answered with `yes` or `no`.

How can I `strongly disagree` that "I click on ads that inerest me"?

That doesn't make much sense.

Or, how can I `strongly disagree` about the fact that I use an ad-blocker?  Either I use one or I don't.

These are YES/NO questions.  How can you rate a yes or no answer?

Perhaps a better way would be to ask, "How often do you use an ad-blocker" and allow the user to say, "Very Often", "Often", "Sometimes", "Never", etc.

Or, maybe the question would be better split into parts in order to provide better information:

- Do you use an ad-blocker?
- How often do you use an ad-blocker?
- How often do you click on ads that interest you?
- Do you appreciate the advertising on SE?

---

**What types of purchases are you involved in?**

Ah, this is another one!  You are given a checklist of things to choose from, such as "hardware", "servers", etc. and then, and THEN there is `consultant` - honestly, I've never seen a `consultant` for sale in Best Buy! Ha ha!

I think that is a bit strange, no?

---

**Which of the following best describes your occupation?**

I think this question should allow you to choose multiples.  What if I am the "back-end developer" AND the "front-end developer" AND the "customer support" AND the "web-developer"....   The question asks what best describes you, but all of those best describe me.  Sometimes we IT guys just plain do everything, especially in the smaller operations.

All that being said, I actually kind of enjoyed taking the survey!  If, whilst using my ad-blocker, that is a way I can *give back* to Stack Overflow, then I'll fill out the survey next year too.

Comment: I don't think they are yes/no at all. You would strongly disagree if you never ever ever not even once did it, and disagree less strongly if you rarely did it, neutral if you did it sometimes but not all the time, up to strongly agree if you do it every chance you get. No problem. (And yes that applies to ad blockers too, since you might use multiple browsers and devices.)

Comment: The columns would then be called "Very Often", "Often","Sometimes", etc.  You can't "disagree" about the frequency of an action.  A frequency is a fact, not an opinion.  "I agree" or "I disagree" or "I strongly agree" expresses an opinion.  The column headers don't make sense.  However, "yes" and "no" can at least express the frequency of whether the fact happens or not.

Comment: Maybe you use an ad blocker, but you feel kinda bad about it :)

Comment: Why would you feel bad about it? It seems to me that if you use an ad-blocker it is because you either 1. don't have any money (like me), 2. want a clean environment (like me) 3. are not interested in shopping whilst solving problems (like me), 4. don't want the distractions (like me).  But don't get me wrong - ads support SE, I completely understand that.  If I were in a different situation, I might not use an ad-blocker.

Comment: In my case, I can't feel bad about it - even though I believe in supporting SE.  So my way of supporting SE is to be an HONEST and CONSCIENTIOUS user.  I don't cheat, I make honest votes that I really believe, I try to answer questions and try to make valuable comments.  I also try to not make comments that are rude or sarcastic (you forget sometimes; I went back and cleaned up this very post!).

Comment: I hire consultants all the time.

Comment: Perhaps, but a "consultant" is out of place amoungst the inanimate objects, and represents a different scope.  Besides you don't *purchase* a consultant, you *hire* them, as you said.

Answer (score 10):

I find it not very surprising but none theless absurd that the survey is so biased to northern america. I'd guess from the lack of english skills and the shear number of users on SO that quite a lot of the community lives in "the rest of the world" I as quite a few others couldn't pick my country (Denmark) and some of the questions are just fun. "How important is a 40 hour work week to you" Well I wouldn't take the job because that's above a standard work week. The salary is immensely funny as well seeing that the wages are a factor of magnitude higher in northern europe than in the states (and so is the taxes) which severly skews the picture you won't find a programmer with an academic background with less than $100000 a year and $150000 is common which is above the top option, similar can be said about most of the questions regarding what's important when choosing a job

Comment: Well, [see for yourself](http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com/geo/countries). 26% from USA alone and if you sum all the "Western" countries I believe you'll cross 50%.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd being from "all the western countries excluding northern american" I can also tell you that there are (as stated) huge differences between northern american and say Scandinavia.

Comment: Agree about salary, but what you expect them to do? Can't see any way to improve the user interface.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Simply use percentiles instead of monetary values. THat's the standard way of handling comparisons accross regions any way

Comment: People doesn't always know how much they earn compared to others in their country; it's much easier to tell the amount you earn.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with the "40 hour work week" - it is just too much. Life quality you gain by working less is worth every euro you don't gain.

Comment: "you won't find a programmer with an academic background with less than $100000 a year and $150000" Uh? I work in the wrong company, or, more likely, the wrong country (France!). Here, experienced programmers rarely get paid more than € 50,000 / year.

Comment: @PhilLho that depends! as I also comment the income taxes are a lot higher (as in 60%)

Answer (score 9):

I got stuck at 2nd page of survey having below question:

**How would you best describe the industry you currently work in?**

I mean to say what if i work for **multiple domains** so user must be able to check multiple answers.

And after filling out some of the questions, questions are being arised in my mind. Why questions are arised? Because there are some of the questions i doubt, why stackoveflow is asking such questions:

1. If you make a software product, how does your company make money? (You can choose more than one) => How this is going to be useful to stackoverflow community?
2. What is your involvement in purchasing products or services for the company you work for? (You can choose more than one)
3. What types of purchases are you involved in? => Why stackoverflow is asking purchase related question?
4. What is your budget for outside expenditures (hardware, software, consulting, etc) for 2013? => Again why stackoverflow is asking such questions? Is stackoverflow planning anything to sell out or opening online stores?
5. What types of purchases are you involved in?

Comment: Those questions are relevant to StackOverflow's advertisers; it will hopefully allow SE to charge more.

Comment: @SLaks yes you are right but then there must be `title` at every page that this is for Advertiser, this is for users or anybody else. What you say? So that particular section will be filled up by only targeted  audience.

Comment: Questions like these are normal. They then show advertisers, "These are the type of people we have, you should target your ads to these types as they have purchasing power or make these products".

Answer (score 9):

This question caused my a high level of anxiety because I believe it is highly ambiguous
[image]

Although I believe I make a software product it isn't something that we sell. You see at our company we have a large group of oompa loompa's, the leaders of these oompa loompa's come to us and tell us to "Build this awesome thing we need" and we do. They then attempt to use it, with varying degrees of success. Once this takes place the head oompa loompas return and make demands for further changes which we oblige this is a cycle that repeats here at my place of employment.

Given this scenario I wasn't sure what to answer, I clicked other but it has since caused me a great deal of anxiety. Are my efforts not to be considered a software product? If not then I could not truthfully answer the question at all yet I was forced to choose "Other"

Again, I find the entire question highly ambiguous.

Comment: I make a software product which is part of a physical product, and isn't sold separately. I guess you could say it's a 'mobile' app - except the mobile is a 60-tonne machine...

Comment: I understood the question as "If **your company** makes a software product, how does your company make money?". My company isn't IT-related at all (manufacturing) and I make internal software, so I just skipped that question.

Answer (score 9):

I wonder if in 'Types of purchase' you shouldn't include **books**?

Comment: Yes, I worried about this one, too. Some people still read technical books!

Answer (score 9):

There should be another option for the last page of `ads` I don't see any ads because of my rep. Because I wasn't sure I just mainly did neutral. But I think doing neutral could affect the results.

If by ads you mean the **Careers** image that never changes. I wouldn't consider that an ad as it never changes and is still a SE product.

Answer (score 9):

"How would you best describe the industry you currently work in?" is missing an option for **government** (at least 15% of the US workforce).

Answer (score 9):

"Including bonus, what is your annual compensation in USD?" -> is this before or after taxes? You know, in the EU is 50% off (no kidding, taxes eat more or less half your wage in many EU countries)

Answer (score 8):

I miss [Caribbean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caribbean) in the list of regions.

Which should I choose? Central America? South America? The [Greater Antilles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_Antilles) like Cuba can be considered part of Central America and the [Lesser Antilles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesser_Antilles) like Curaçao can be considered part of South America. Although technically completely wrong, is it okay to consider my region like that for this survey?

In terms of "regions of the world", [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Regions_of_the_world) considers it to be part of North America, which is IMO incorrect. The [site](https://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/america.htm) as Richard the Kiwi is referring to in his New Zealand defense, Caribbean is mentioned as in "The Americas and the Caribbean", indicating it to be a separate territory. In terms of area and population, the Caribbean is however calculated together with Central America.

To avoid this confusion, it'd make sense if Caribbean becomes a separate entry in the list of regions.

Comment: [According to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antilles) Antilles geographically belong to North or Central America

Comment: But according to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cura%C3%A7ao#Geography) Curaçao is part of South America. Decide yourself )

Answer (score 7):

Why do you ask what my reputation is? Can't you get that information automatically?

Comment: The survey is hosted on a third-party platform, which doesn't integrate with Stack Exchange.

Comment: Maybe just ask for our username then?

Comment: Something tells me the devs have a lot on their plate, like working on the new Area 51, fixing bugs on the Q&A platform, and doing things to make the Q&A better. The survey seems to be something the marketing department is pioneering, which [Alison S](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151795/alison-s) is part of, so they likely don't have a lot of developer support to do the integration. Besides, most of us probably know our reputation anyhow. ;)

Comment: The survey is designed to be at least potentially anonymous. Asking for the username would break that. Plus, there are a lot of duplicate usernames. We'd have to ask for userids or profile links, and I bet more people know their rep than their userid without having to look it up.

Answer (score 6):

Where you ask how much one plans to spend next year, the $5,001-10,000 range is missing.

Answer (score 4):

"Gaming" implies gambling and casino machines.  Is that what was intended?

I make video games.  Broadly that's "entertainment media" (which isn't represented at all) and the specific "video games" (quite different from "gaming") would be a fine entry as well as I know a lot of my peers frequent SO.

My company makes consumer software but we don't sell direct to consumers, we go through retail.  We don't do direct sales to anyone, our products magically appear in retail stores and sales are handled by other companies.  (IOW, there should be a separate spot for "retail packaged software".)

Comment: I think "gaming" is used very, very commonly to refer to consumer video games (PC, console, mobile, etc).

Comment: I also abhor the term "gamer". If you could please address me as an "entertainment mediaer" I would appreciate it.

Comment: If "gaming" *really* implied gambling & casino games, you wouldn't have checked the box.  Did you?

Comment: "Gaming" in a _development_ context refers to the gaming industry, which means casino games.  Why would I have checked that box if I believe this to be the case?  E.g. The American Gaming Industry's [list of careers](http://www.americangaming.org/getinthegame/types-careers).  (Strange to get downvoted for statements of fact but it's not the first time...)

Comment: Lots of various industries use the same word for different meanings. I am aware of and use both meanings of 'gaming'.

Comment: I literally had to read the first sentence a few times to make any sense of it. I was locked in the context of software development. In different contexts words mean different things. E.g. being a vet you can and have to use the word bitch on and off and it's not swearing it's accurate. gaming in a software development context does not imply gambling or can any one tell how to place $20 on red using Visual studio? :)

Answer (score 4):

Mozambique is not on the locations list :-(...

Answer (score 3):

I got my sticker for participating in the survey!! :D

[image: Sticker]

Comment: I was severely disappointed in the sticker design/quality/all-of-the-above. It was free, but had they told us what they were sending ahead of time I could have saved them an envelope and postage...

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty disappointed too

Answer (score 2):

Some questions got me paranoid. How does a company make money from mobile app?

Comment: By selling it, perhaps?

Comment: I go with @AnnaLear, nowadays, there was many companies who are developing more mobile apps and sell it in the app store, google play and also by selling it to the direct customers.

Comment: Facebook has recently taken their advertising to users on their mobile application, tripling their ad revenue and impressions.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in when you ask about what your industry is do you provide 'Web Marketing' ...  Is this 'Web Services'?   I think these are 2 majorly different areas.

Answer (score 1):

Please allow to skip questions... page 3 is an overkill, I don't have time to read all that!

Answer (score 1):

The Radio Buttons in the survey aren't clickable on my iPad mini.

Answer (score 1):

There is only a limited list of technologies for which I am supposed to be exited? My favorite technology is not among the possible choice, what a shame.

Answer (score 1):

Awesome!

I'm Czech - not a choice,
a student - not a choice,
don't make money off anything programming related - not a choice, etc.

Truly, a well thought-out survey. I applaud you.

Answer (score 0):

Gave up after it became obvious this is about targeting ads and Careers 2.0 posts rather than actually improving the site.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of adding "What Country or Region do you live in?" it should be better to add the list of all countries.

[image]