# Where is my country in Annual User Survey 2013

Tags: support, stack-overflow-developer-survey

I am from a small Asian country called "[Nepal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nepal)". When I saw [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158456/stack-overflow-annual-user-survey) I try to participate in survey. But the first question make me sad. Where is my country?

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Select `Other Asia`

Comment: why down vote :(

Comment: Nepal is too localized? Meta Stack Overflow is so unkind ... :P.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should probably use "Other Asia".

I assume the list is based on the frequency of users from certain countries.

So if you want to have your country included in the next survey, try to make more Stack Overflow users in your country.

Comment: Considering that we also have "Other Europe", it probably takes a lot of Nepalese users to get a separate entry. :-)

Comment: To be honest, it really isn't that hard to include another few countries.  This should have been done.