# When will we get the stickers from the Stack Overflow survey?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, stack-overflow-developer-survey, stickers

So I took the entire annual Stack Overflow 2012 User Survey, and when do the stickers come?

They said we'd get stickers for filling it out. Just curious, it's been a while ^_^

Note: I do live in the US

Comment: also waiting.So far from US.Its from Nepal

Comment: it hasn't been that long has it? 2 weeks maybe?

Comment: Isn't 6-8 weeks, or is 42 the answer to this question too? `;)`

Comment: I got mine a few days ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FYI: in a comment to the original post: [Stack Overflow Annual User Survey 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158456/stack-overflow-annual-user-survey)

> Stickers will be mailed out this week via First Class Mail. So you should have them next week. Please let me know when you get them! – Alison S Jan 10 at 20:35

So they should be very close to arriving.

Comment: STICKERS!!!!!!!!

Comment: Sweet!! :D Can't wait

Answer (score 7):

I just got my sticker (singular) and I'm pretty disappointed.

Now, I know it's free and all (yes, I'm an entitled whiny child, etc), but hear me out:

It's not the same sticker you can get if you send a SASE to them which are really nice vinyl stickers. It's a crappy paper sticker... the kind that rips off in sections and forces you to use goo gone or something similar to remove all the crap it leaves behind. Also just a circular cut sticker of a web 2.0 badge, white background included, with a white stack overflow symbol in the center.

Again, it was free, but if I knew that was going to be what they sent I wouldn't have wasted their time or money on the envelope/postage (those were definitely worth way more).

***Bracing for impact***

Comment: You were too kind in your assessment.

Comment: If it's any consolation, this makes all us foreigners feel slightly better about missing out :D

Comment: At least you got a sticker, all that was in my envelope was a paper slip saying "Thank you for participating in the Stack Overflow Annual User Survey!" wtf?

Comment: You're not missing out, trust me.

Comment: @WebChemist same here-- nothing but a 4x8.5 piece of paper saying "Thank you for participating in the Stack Overflow Annual User Survey!"  Seems incredibly wasteful.