# Stack Overflow Message?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-developer-survey

In the [Annual Survey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211850/stack-overflow-annual-user-survey-2013-edition) for 2013, one question is about the preferred way to be contacted by a recruiter. One of the options is "Stack Overflow Message".

What does that mean? As far as I know there [is no messaging mechanism for contacting other users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user).

Comment: This most likely referring to [StackOverflow Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/). I believe you can message users that are signed up about job openings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated, thanks for the heads up!

The option is now changed to "Stack Overflow Careers Message".